# Is there a single word to describe a person who bests suits the description of the old fashioned expression - "penny-wise and pound-foolish"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am curious to know if there is a single word to describe a person who bests suits the description of the old fashioned expression - "penny-wise and pound-foolish"
​
As per Cambridge dictionary, this expression means the following -

"to be extremely careful about small amounts of money and not careful enough about larger amounts of money'

Please note that this question is not a duplicate of an earlier question which was asking a term for describing someone who is "profligate with small expenditures but foolishly thrifty with big ones". If I have understood this correctly, I assume this is quite the opposite of what I have asked here. If my understanding is incorrect, I have no issues with flagging this as duplicate.

Comment: You're going  to have to make the distinction clearer, perhaps use bold (sparingly!), because I nearly voted to close this question as a duplicate. I would also suggest asking about expressions or idioms. I don't think you'll have a single word that covers it all.

Comment: *penny-wise-and-pound-foolish*